# Restrict Azure Active Directory app access to specific tenants

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm hoping to use the Microsoft Identity Platform - Azure Active Directory - to manage authentication for my app.

I using the v2.0 endpoint.

I've registered my application in the new Application Registration Portal (`apps.dev.microsoft.com`), and it is now showing up in the main Azure portal under `Azure Active Directory > App registrations`

I need to restrict access to my application to certain organisations - I'm working on the assumption this means I need to allow access to a specific set of AD tenants.

In the application manifest, there's a `signInAudience` property, the options for which are `AzureADMyOrg`, `AzureADMultipleOrgs` and `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

`AzureADMultipleOrgs` sounds the closest to what I'm looking for, but so far it means anyone with an AD account can access my app.

I've come across documentation for an `orgRestrictions` property (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/application.md) which sounds useful but it just says `Reserved for future use`

I assume this is a common use case e.g. only allow access to organisations that subscribe to your product, but I don't see a straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I assume this is a common use case e.g. only allow access to organisations that subscribe to your product, but I don't see a straightforward way to do it.

Yes it is, and most multi-tenant samples showcase this.
Currently there is no way to say that a given app should allow login from X and Y, so it'll have to allow all Azure AD tenants.
(though that is a feature that has been heavily requested)
Then after authentication, your app can check the `tid` claim.
You could for example check from a database if this tenant has a valid subscription.
If they don't, redirect them to an error page and don't log them in.

Comment: Hi, do you know if they implemented this in the meanwhile? I am also searching for this exact same feature and couldn't find anything about it (or i am looking for the wrong terms)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not available yet

Comment: Thank you @juunas for letting me know. I kept looking for it but did not rly find anything useful yet. The closest thing to achive this (on a per user base seems to be this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users However, it had no  effect on my existing App Registration :/
If you have a linkt to the feature request (at Microsoft User Voice) can you please share it? I also did not find this anywhere. 
Many thx!