# Azure AD multi-tenant app - restrict tenants that can sign up

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to restrict a multi-tenant Azure AD application, so that only a select few tenants are allowed to sign-up?

As mentioned in this [article](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fdevelop%2Fhowto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant&data=02%7C01%7Csvarukal%40microsoft.com%7C1945fb54247a48c7ab2b08d664a46c0a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636807054904659747&sdata=AryQ6t9bfxLtvtCarj1FJzh%2BJ8YjojMBJU%2FlU9PEuOU%3D&reserved=0), the web app can validate the user to check if the issuer value is part of a list of their approved tenants. However, this happens after the fact that the user is already signed up for their web app. Is it possible to restrict the sign up process to limit to an approved list of tenants?

Comment: Not at the moment no.

Answer (score 4):

You can restrict access to tenants but cannot restrict sign-up. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions

You could, however, have your service keep a whitelist of tenants which are allowed to call your API, and check that the token has the correct issuer or tid claim. (See [Restrict Azure Active Directory app access to specific tenants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682803/restrict-azure-active-directory-app-access-to-specific-tenants))

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's exactly what I recommended to my customer. Ideally it would help if there is a way to restrict the sign up too. :)

Answer (score -1):

Srinivas, you can restrict the application so that only some specific users are able to sign up by configuring the application on portal.

1. You need to find the application you created. Go to the azure portal, click the Azure Active Directory, select Enterprise Applications, Select All Applications to view a list of all your applications. If you do not see the application you want show up here, use the various filters at the top of the All applications list to restrict the list or scroll down the list to locate your application.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi29I.png)
2. Enable user assignment. Select the your application, go to the properties, locate the setting User assignment required? and set it to Yes. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSAhe.png)
3. Assign users and groups to the app. Select the Users and groups, select the Add user, and chose the users you want to allow to sign up, then you can restrict the sign up process to limit to these tenants.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNDxW.png)

You can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) for more detail.

Comment: Question is about multi tenant applications whete you may not necessarily have access to oyher tenants