# How to add Enterprise Application in customer tenant with single tenant App Registration in developer tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication, azure-identity

As a small SaaS provider I currently have an app service which I host in my tenant and it uses Azure AD for IAM. I have two customers and there is a separate app service instance and database for each customer in different regions. I also have created two additional tenants for each customer and within each customer tenant I have an app registration (single tenant) linked to an enterprise application. User accounts are created within a customer tenant AAD and given access to the enterprise application with one of the corresponding app registration roles.

This all works fine however one of my customers has recently implemented Office 365 in their own tenant and would like to use their O365 user accounts to sign in to my application instead of the user accounts within the tenant I created for them.

I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) and this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service) and updated the **Issuer Url** to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/customer-tenant-id/v2.0" in the app service authentication provider properties. This didn't allow my customer tenant to access my app but once I changed my host app registration to multi-tenant it worked. However it didn't prevent other test tenants from also accessing my app so going down the multi-tenant path seems to introduce unnecessary complexity and risk especially when there will only ever be a one to one relationship between customer and app service instance.

Therefore since each instance of my app is only used by one customer I would like to keep the single tenant design. However I cannot find a way to implement the app registration and roles within my tenant and have the customer only have the enterprise application in their tenant. Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. However, maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842779/1163423

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Martin Brandl in comment section you can refer the thread link.

When we are adding application to azure ad as an enterprise application, we will be having an option to add it as a single tenant or multitenant application  based on our requirement.

1.Single-tenant apps are only available in the tenant they were registered in, also known as their home tenant.

2.Multi-tenant apps are available to users in both their home tenant and other tenant

Single tenant: All user and guest accounts in your directory can use your application or API.

Multi-tenant: All users and guests with a work or school account from Microsoft can use your application or API. This includes schools and businesses that use Microsoft 365.

As you already configured your app to multi-tenant and  you want to restrict the access for some tenants You can use a feature called tenant restriction .
With tenant restrictions, organizations can specify the list of tenants that their users are permitted to access. Azure AD then only grants access to these permitted tenants.
Here is the reference doc to Use [tenant restrictions to manage access to SaaS apps - Azure AD |](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions)

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I tested this and found that trying to authenticate with an account from another tenant (which I created under my subscription) that even though the restriction was in place the app still appeared under the Enterprise Applications for this new tenant which is what I'm trying to avoid. Otherwise anybody from any tenant could try and login and although they might not succeed it still creates a new enterprise application instance. Is this possible to avoid?